# Is there a library that would perform segmented linear regression in python?

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

There is a package named segmented in R. Is there a similar package in python?

Comment: Is there anything specific that you need? For known break points, this can just be modeled by an interaction with a indicator function (0 before, 1 after the break) or a linear spline. The first approach has a jump, the second approach results in a connected piecewise regression line.

Comment: LINEAR-TREE (sklearn wrapper): https://github.com/cerlymarco/linear-tree

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, currently there isn't a package in Python that does segmented linear regression as thoroughly as those in R (e.g. [R packages listed in this blog post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-for-ecologists-putting-together-a-piecewise-regression/)). Alternatively, you can use a Bayesian Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm in Python to create your segmented model.

Segmented linear regression, as implemented by all the R packages in the above link, doesn't permit extra parameter constraints (i.e. priors), and because these packages take a frequentist approach, the resulting model doesn't give you probability distributions for the model parameters (i.e. breakpoints, slopes, etc). Defining a segmented model in [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/), which is frequentist, is even more restrictive because the model requires a fixed x-coordinate breakpoint.

You can design a segmented model in Python using the Bayesian Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm [emcee](http://dan.iel.fm/emcee/current/). Jake Vanderplas wrote a useful [blog post](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/06/14/frequentism-and-bayesianism-4-bayesian-in-python/) and [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5018.pdf) for how to implement emcee with comparisons to PyMC and PyStan.

Example:

- Segmented model with data:

[image: Segmented regression]

- Probability distributions of fit parameters:

[image]

- [Link to code for segmented model](https://github.com/stharrold/ARCHIVED_2015_Harrold_SDSSJ1600/blob/master/code/utils.py#L1241-L1546).
- [Link to (large) ipython notebook](https://gist.github.com/stharrold/33120aaf182b66983ee8).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This is an implementation of my own.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# parameters for setup
n_data = 20

# segmented linear regression parameters
n_seg = 3

np.random.seed(0)
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

# example 1
#xs = np.sort(np.random.rand(n_data))
#ys = np.random.rand(n_data) * .3 + np.tanh(5* (xs -.5))

# example 2
xs = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
ys = np.random.rand(n_data) * .3 + np.tanh(3*xs)

dys = np.gradient(ys, xs)

rgr = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_leaf_nodes=n_seg)
rgr.fit(xs.reshape(-1, 1), dys.reshape(-1, 1))
dys_dt = rgr.predict(xs.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()

ys_sl = np.ones(len(xs)) * np.nan
for y in np.unique(dys_dt):
    msk = dys_dt == y
    lin_reg = LinearRegression()
    lin_reg.fit(xs[msk].reshape(-1, 1), ys[msk].reshape(-1, 1))
    ys_sl[msk] = lin_reg.predict(xs[msk].reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
    ax0.plot([xs[msk][0], xs[msk][-1]],
             [ys_sl[msk][0], ys_sl[msk][-1]],
             color='r', zorder=1)

ax0.set_title('values')
ax0.scatter(xs, ys, label='data')
ax0.scatter(xs, ys_sl, s=3**2, label='seg lin reg', color='g', zorder=5)
ax0.legend()

ax1.set_title('slope')
ax1.scatter(xs, dys, label='data')
ax1.scatter(xs, dys_dt, label='DecisionTree', s=2**2)
ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is now a Python package called `piecewise-regression` that implements similar tools to the segmented R package, using the same algorithm.

You can get it from pip

```
pip install piecewise-regression
```

There are [full docs](https://piecewise-regression.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html), a [github repo](https://github.com/chasmani/piecewise-regression), and an [accompanying paper](https://joss.theoj.org/papers/10.21105/joss.03859).

Here's an example fit:

[image: piecewise-regression example]

It's very easy-to-use, [code examples here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Pwv6LqwZU8Zbl0VZH6cwOTwoRzm3CPPC#offline=true&sandboxMode=true/).

Full disclosure: I wrote the package.